# Vue js - how can I pass this property to a component in a loop?

Tags: vue.js

I have a custom component that conditionally renders either a link to `path` or a span for disabled link if the supplied `path-disabled` method determines so, the internals of which are unimportant other than it works when used like this:

```
<li>
  <conditional-link path="/step/1" :path-disabled="pathDisabled">
    <span class="number">1</span>
    Step one
  </conditional-link>
</li>
```

But if I do this it fails:

```
<li v-for="route in stepPaths['/step'].subRoutes">
  <conditional-link path="{{route.fullPath}}" :path-disabled="pathDisabled">
    <span class="number">{{route.number}}</span>
    {{route.title}} 

    this outputs correct path:
    {{route.fullPath}}

  </conditional-link>
</li>
```

The `path` property value is the litteral string `{{route.fullPath}}`.

I tried `path="route.fullPath"` but then the path is the litteral string `route.fullPath`.

How do I get the path value into the path property in a loop? The variable is correct as it renders fine within the inside of the component.

Answer (score 1):

OK it was easy so in case any other newbies run into this, you have to bind the object in the v-for to be able to use the object directly:

```
<li v-for="route in stepPaths" :route="route">
   <conditional-link :path="route.fullPath" ...
```